# How to pivot wider a table with tidyverse if some factor levels are empty

Tags: r

I want to reshape a dataframe from long to wide format. The code is:

```
structure(list(periodo = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), lugar = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "B", "B", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B"), nihss = structure(c(2L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
6L), levels = c("0", "1-4", "5-15", "16-20", "20+", "9999"), class = "factor"), 
    porcent = c(5, 56, 17, 22, 1, 12, 53, 15, 18, 1, 30, 30, 
    40, 6, 37, 27, 28, 2)), row.names = c(NA, -18L), class = "data.frame")
```

One column, `nihss`, is a factor variable, with ordered levels:

```
stroke$nihss <- factor(stroke$nihss, levels = c("0","1-4","5-15","16-20","20+","9999"))
```

Some levels are empty for some combinations of the named variables, `periodo` and `lugar`, in pivot_wider.
My code to pivot these data is:

```
stroke %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = c(lugar, periodo), values_from = porcent, values_fill = 0) %>% 
  kable()
```

The code works as expected, and the reshaped table has four new columns. However, the nihss' levels are not ordered according to the original order. The first ("0") and the last ("9999") appears after the remaining categories:

```
nihss   A_0 B_0 A_1 B_1
1-4 5   12  0   6
5-15    56  53  30  37
16-20   17  15  30  27
20+ 22  18  40  28
0   0   1   0   0
9999    0   1   0   2
```

I expect to get a pivoted table, where the levels of the factor are shown as originally were ordered. That is:

`"0","1-4","5-15","16-20","20+","9999"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `dplyr::arrange()` to your output, like:

```r
[...]

 stroke$nihss <- factor(stroke$nihss, levels = c("0","1-4","5-15","16-20","20+","9999"))

 stroke |>
   tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from = c(lugar, periodo), values_from = porcent, values_fill = 0) |>
   dplyr::arrange(nihss) |>
   knitr::kable()
```

| nihss | A_0 | B_0 | A_1 | B_1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 1-4 | 5 | 12 | 0 | 6 |
| 5-15 | 56 | 53 | 30 | 37 |
| 16-20 | 17 | 15 | 30 | 27 |
| 20+ | 22 | 18 | 40 | 28 |
| 9999 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 2 |

<sup>Created on 2023-06-29 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>